# Jquery toggle not showing div after hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

When you click 'Darrien Tu' the text on the far right disappears but it doesn't come back when you reclick the name.

https://jsfiddle.net/gkrh0ok0/1/

```
$("#nav_list").click(function () {     
    $(".sidebar-right").toggle();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have check the fiddle. There is one issue in **.sidebar-right**

You have given `margin-left:80%` instead of give `right:20px`

This might help to solve your issue.

I have update your script code :

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
        $nav_list = $('#nav_list');

        $nav_list.click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
            $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open').after($(".sidebar-right").toggle('slow'));

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Add comment to this code**

```
<script>
        /*$("#nav_list").click(function() { 
// assumes element with id='button'
$(".sidebar-right").toggle();

        });*/

</script>
```

Comment: I have been... fiddling with it as well, and it looks like it has something to do with the `margin-left` rule. I think when the sidebar comes out the margin in recalculated, but when the sidebar is hidden it does not recalculate again. If you resize the box where the page is displayed it will recalculate. Not completely sure why that is.

Comment: The problem is when I give it 'code' right:20px 'code' it starts to overlap the left div when I shrink the browser.

Comment: @Bhavin Solanki    Thanks! It still doesn't like the margin-left rule so if I use a right:50px; rule it will still cause an overlap over the left div when the brower resizes (I added pic to OP).

Comment: Solved. I just put left:90%;